# extract data from excel files and structure them into hashes

Tags: perl

I have a three columns Excel file,which has the following pattern

```
12   A    P1  
23   B    P5
24   C    P2
15   D    P1
06   E    P5
```

The structure underlying this data set is that, 
`P1` contains `A` and `D`; `A` corresponds to `12` and `D` corresponds to `15`
`P2` contains `C`; `C` corresponds to `24`
`P5` contains `B` and `E`; `B` corresponds to `23` and `E` corresponds to `06`

I want to represent this kind of structure in a hashed structure i.e., use `P1` as a key to point to a hash, and `A` is used as the key for this second level hash. Is there a way to implement this in Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`](http://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel) can be used to parse `.xls` files. Below is a sample program that builds the desired data structure.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $parser    = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new;
my $workbook  = $parser->parse( shift or die "Please provide a file\n" );
my $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet(0);

my %data;
for my $row ( 0 .. $worksheet->row_range ) {
    my $value     = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 0 )->value;
    my $key       = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 1 )->value;
    my $super_key = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, 2 )->value;
    $data{$super_key}->{$key} = $value;
}

print Dumper \%data;
```

#### Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'P5' => {
                    'E' => '06',
                    'B' => '23'
                  },
          'P2' => {
                    'C' => '24'
                  },
          'P1' => {
                    'A' => '12',
                    'D' => '15'
                  }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to process data in spreadsheets in the past. If you are dealing with a small number of Excel files, export them manually to CSV files using a spreadsheet software such as Excel. Then parse the CSV file, and store the cell values in a hash of hashes in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper::Simple;

my $file = "";
my @row = ();
my $rowidx = 1;
my %hh = (); # hash of hashes

open( INFILE, "input.csv" ) or die("Can not open input file: $!");

while ( $file = <INFILE> ) {
    @row = parse($file);
    chomp(@row);

    $hh{ $row[2] }{ $row[1] } = $row[0];
    #warn Dumper %hh; # debug

    $rowidx++;
}

close(INFILE);

warn Dumper %hh;

exit;

sub parse {
    my @newrow  = ();
    my $columns = shift; # read next row
    push( @newrow, $+ ) while $columns =~ m{"([^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*)",?|([^,]+),?|,}gx; # parse and store columns to array 
    push( @newrow, undef ) if substr( $columns, -1, 1 ) eq ',';
    return @newrow;
}
```

Running this gives

```
$ more input.csv
12,A,P1
23,B,P5
24,C,P2
15,D,P1
06,E,P5
$ ./ReadCSV.pl input.csv 
%hh = (
    'P5' => {
              'E' => '06',
              'B' => '23'
            },
    'P2' => {
              'C' => '24'
            },
    'P1' => {
              'A' => '12',
              'D' => '15'
            }
  );
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use a module designed to handle csv, such as [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV).

Answer (score 1):

There's the [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.59/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm) function which does a pretty good job of parsing a regular `*.xls` spreadsheet.

Fortunately, there's an *extension* called [Spreadsheet::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~dmow/Spreadsheet-XLSX-0.13-withoutworldwriteables/lib/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm) that works with `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` to also read `*.xlsx` spreadsheets too. The methods used in `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` work with both `*.xls` and `*.xlsx` files if you also have `Spreadsheet::XLSX` also installed.

Answer (score 0):

What version of excel are the files formatted in?
I have had a very good experience with reading from (and writing to) .xls files using the modules [`Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`](http://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel) ([`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](http://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel) for output)

Unfortunately, I did this 4 years ago and the .xlsx format was not as prevalent, so I can't speak for those.